# How to modify a many-to-many collection using django rest framework

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I am trying to create an endpoint where, having a `User` entity, I can add / remove existing `Group` entities to `user.groups` many-to-many field. But when I try to do it, django-rest-framework tries to create new group objects instead of finding existing ones.

I have defined two serializers where `UserSerializer` has a nested `GroupSerializer`:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['id', 'name']


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'groups']

    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        data = validated_data.copy()
        groups = data.pop('groups', [])
        for key, val in data.items():
            setattr(instance, key, val)
        instance.groups.clear()
        for group in groups:
            instance.groups.add(group)
        return instance

    def create(self, validated_data):
        data = validated_data.copy()
        groups = data.pop('groups', [])
        instance = self.Meta.model.objects.create(**data)
        for group in groups:
            instance.groups.add(group)
        return instance
```

When I send a JSON through a PUT REST call (from django-rest-framework web interface):

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "username": "user5@example.com",
    "email": "user5@example.com",
    "groups": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "AAA"
        }
    ]
}
```

I expect serializer to find the Group with given id and add it to User. But instead, it tries to create a new user group and fails with duplicate key error:

```
{
    "groups": [
        {
            "name": [
                "group with this name already exists."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I searched over the internet and debugged myself and found no solution to this use case.

The `create` and `update` methods inside `UserSerializer`class are never reached.

**Edit:** as asked, here are my views and urls:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
```

Urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Comment: Please provide the views and urls

Comment: I debugged and saw that the problem is not withing views/urls. The `serializer.save()` method is the place where exception is thrown. More specifically, `serializer.is_valid()`. I don't want to clutter the question with unneeded info (will become less readable).

Comment: The way you initialize the serializer object will cause different flow of doing `serializer.save()`. That's why I suggest your providing the view function since the initialization may be done in view function.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that! I edited the question and added views and urls.

Comment: How did you send the request? Since you use `ModelViewSet` and did not override any methods of it and just use default routers, the way that triggering serializer would depend on what HTTP method you are using. In this case you are expecting doing `update()`, and that means you should use `PUT` method here. If you use `POST`, then `create()` will be called.

Comment: I used PUT, I sent it through django-rest-framwework web interface. (Edited the page to contain that info just now)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be the validation error due to a nested serializer model that contains unique constraint, see this [post](https://medium.com/django-rest-framework/dealing-with-unique-constraints-in-nested-serializers-dade33b831d9). According to the article, DRF did not handle this condition since it's hard to realize if the serializer is a nested serializer within another one. And that's why the `create()` and `update()` never been reached since the validation is done before calling them.

The way to work around this is to remove the uniqueness validator manually in `GroupSerializer` as follow:

```py
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['id', 'name']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'name': {'validators': []},
        }
```

BTW, there are some points that can be improved or should be corrected in your `update()` and `create()` code. Firstly, you didn't do  `instance.save()` so the instance won't be update after the whole process done. Second, the `groups` are just a list of dictionary, and you should not add object that way. The following are the modification based on your OP code:

```py
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        data = validated_data.copy()
        groups = data.pop('groups', [])
        for key, val in data.items():
            setattr(instance, key, val)
        instance.save()                     # This will indeed update DB values

        group_ids = [g['id'] for g in groups]
        instance.groups.clear()
        instance.groups.add(*group_ids)     # Add all groups once. Also you can replace these two lines with
                                            # instance.groups.set(group_ids)
        return instance
```

Comment: Thank you fort the answer, code improvement tips and a link to a post about it! There is a small issue I found with line `group_ids = [g['id'] for g in groups]` - basically, `validated_data` has`groups: [OrderedDict([('name', 'AAA')])]` so I had to use `name` instead of `id` for now (until I find a way to get `id` to not be lost). Interestingly, `id` is there in `request.data` but is not there inside serializer's `validated_data`.

Comment: You're right. That's my fault. I forgot the `id` will not present in `validated_data` since it is defaultly set to `read_only=True` (If you didn't specify extra configs on it). Thus indeed you should use `name` here but not `id`

Comment: I tried `id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=False)` and still `id` was not present in `validated_data`. The only way I found it to be working is by using: `serializers.ModelField(model_field=Group()._meta.get_field('id'))`

Answer (score 0):

Though am late, here is how I did it, adding to Tsang-Yi Shen answer. However this worked for me because I was using `django-role-permissions` https://django-role-permissions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup.html

For the group serializer am only interested in the name.

```
    from rolepermissions.roles import assign_role
    

    class GroupModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        class Meta:
            model = Group
            fields = ['name']
            extra_kwargs = {
                'name': {'validators': []},
            }
        def get_name(self, obj):
            """
            This method modifies the way the name field is returned in a get request.
            """
            return [group.name for group in obj.objects.all()]
```

In the `UserSerializer`, I modify the `groups` field to be returned as a list of groups a user belongs to, and received as a `list` instead of an `OrderedDict` in the JSON payload for creating a User,  which can look something like this:

```
{
  "email": "testuser@example.com",
  "username": "testuser",
  "name": "Test User",
  "password": "password123",
  "groups": ["doctor", "nurse", ]
}
```

```
    class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
        groups = ListField(required=False, default=[], write_only=True)
        user_groups = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ["id", "email", "username", "name", "password", "groups", "user_groups"]
            depth = 2
        
        def get_user_groups(self, obj):
            """
            This method modifies the way the `groups` field is returned in a get request.
            """
            return [group.name for group in obj.groups.all()]
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            password = validated_data.pop('password')
            gropus_to_add_user = validated_data.pop("groups")
            user = User(**validated_data)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
    
            for group_name in groups_to_add_user:
                # The assign_role function adds the user to a group. 
                # In this case group and roles may mean the same thing.
                assign_role(user, group_name)
    
            return user
```

You will have something like this when creating a user, here am using Swagger:

[image]